# the simple foreign key in the same attribute of Dno and Dnumber

Tags: mysql

!the code of the mysql][CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWxPA.png)

i want to know why i cannot add the foreign key constraint. Dno and Dnumber have the same attribute, but the result has the problem. Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Create table employee04
(Dno int not null default 1,);

create table department04
(Dnumber int not null);

alter table employee04 add constraint EMPFK foreign key(Dno) references department04(Dnumber);

Comment: You may paste your code here. I think no one here will like to click on that **1**!

Comment: sorry, i have posted the main code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both column have to have the same default value.Dno in employee is default 1 ,Dnumber in department has default null.

```
ALTER TABLE employee04
ALTER Dno SET DEFAULT NULL
```

> While SET DEFAULT is allowed by the MySQL Server, it is rejected as
>   invalid by InnoDB. CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements using this
>   clause are not allowed for InnoDB tables.

[**Doc**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Maybe try `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Comment: even i have the same default value, i still cannot be success

Comment: Do you have data in those tables?

Comment: Maybe try ON DELETE SET NULL?sorry, i have just learnt MYSQL. so,how can i solve the problem?